# Is $(g \ast f ) '= g'\ast f$ true?

Tags: convolution, lebesgue-measure

Take $ f \in L^{1} (\mathbb{R})$, and $ g \in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$, with $g$ almost everywhere differentiable and such that $g' \in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$.

Prove or disprove: $(f \ast g) \in C^1({\mathbb{R}})$ $(f\ast g)'=f\ast g'$.

I think this is not true. Take for $g$ the cantor lebesgue function. Extended in the whole real line so $g( x)=0 $ for $x\leq 0$ and $g(x)=1$ for $x \geq1$. And choose $f$ the characteristic function of $[-1,1]$.

The cantor  [lebesgue function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) is continuous, and have the property that $g'=0$ a.e..
If the prove or disprove statement was true then $f \ast g$ should be constant, but this is not the case. Since for $g\ast f(10) = 0$ but $g\ast f(0)\neq 0  $.

Am I missing something? Thank you for your time.

Comment: I think it might be true for $f(x)=c$...

Comment: @abiessu What I meant for prove or disprove: Prove that the statement holds for all such $f,g$ otherwise provide a counterexample

Answer (score 2):

Let
$$
f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{l}
e^{1/(x^2-1)}&\text{when }|x|\lt1\\
0&\text{when }|x|\ge1\\
\end{array}\right.
$$
and
$$
g(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{l}
1&\text{when }|x|\lt1\\
0&\text{when }|x|\ge1\\
\end{array}\right.
$$
$f\in L^1$ and $g\in L^\infty$. Furthermore, $g'(x)=0$ almost everywhere.

It is easy to see that since
$$
\begin{align}
\int_\mathbb{R}f\ast g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_\mathbb{R}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\int_\mathbb{R}g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&\gt0
\end{align}
$$
Thus, $(f\ast g)'(x)$ is not identically $0$.

Since $g'(x)=0$ almost everywhere, $f\ast g'(x)=0$ for all $x$.

Note that this result is different if we treat $g'(x)$ as a distribution.